# Trocar tabela DEFAULT do Auth do Laravel Framework 5.8.15

Tags: php, laravel, autenticação, auth

Boa noite, gostaria de saber como utilizar o auth do Laravel porém com uma tabela diferente, vi alguns artigos na internet mas não consegui mudar ainda.

Tentei sobrescrever o método protected $table = 'nome_da_tabela'; 
Porém sem sucesso, ele não autentica por lá, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Model de acesso ao banco:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'autenticar';

    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password_hash',
    ];

    protected $username = 'email';

    protected $email = 'email';

    protected $password = 'password_hash';


    // protected $hidden = [
    //     'password', 'remember_token',
    // ];

    // protected $casts = [
    //     'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    // ];
}
```

Comment: porque trocar o nome da tabela? e quais campos existem nessa tabela? porque esse protected ai `$username`, `$email`????

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver criando uma nova model e sobrescrevendo alguns métodos e variáveis do padrão Auth do Laravel:

Nova Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User2 extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'udropship_vendor';
    protected $primaryKey = 'vendor_id';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password_hash'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password_hash'
    ];

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return bcrypt($this->password_hash);
    }
}
```

E no arquivo config/Auth.php sobrescrevi o providers para minha nova model, segue o código:

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User2::class,
        ],
```

Outro detalhe muito importante e que perdi boas horas tentando resolver, o padrão de login do Auth Laravel ao enviar a senha ele faz um bcrypt no password, como meu banco tinha senha do tipo MD5 eu demorei em encontrar o problema, eu acabei criando um método para ler e mudar o tipo da senha como podem ver na minha model, método:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return bcrypt($this->password_hash);
    }
```